# Enable compression with JSch

Tags: java, compression, port, jsch, forwarding

My problem is simple, I tried to enable compression over a local port forwarding connection I do though jsch. My localport forwarding works fine but I can not make compression. I see no defference in data if I add the bellow code or I dont add it.

```
session.setConfig("compression.s2c", "zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none");
session.setConfig("compression.c2s", "zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none");
session.setConfig("compression_level", "9");
```

I don't know why it doesnt work, even if I have changed my sshd_config file and I have enabled Compression, 'Compression yes'.

Any suggestions? and is it possible to open a chanell for localforwarding like?

Thank you

Comment: Try calling the `rekey` method. Quoting the API: `This is necessary for some changes on the configuration to become active, like compression or encryption mode. `

Comment: Thank you for your answer @copeg but I call it after or before the connection? thank you

Comment: I believe `rekey` should be called after creating the connection. If it does not work, I'd recommend posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem you experience.

Comment: Calling `rekey` on a new connection does not make sense.

Comment: Enable [JSch logging](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Logger.java.html) and include the log into your question. A verbose server log would be useful too. Btw, did you restart your SSH server after enabling `Compression`?

Comment: Did you call `session.setConfig` before you call `session.connect`?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Yes, I restarted my ssh server after I enabled it.

Comment: @Nat yes I called set config after I did connect

Comment: You should do it before not after.

Comment: What do you mean, I restart my ssh server then do compression and dont restart it again?

Comment: I mean you should apply all the config by calling `session.setConfig` before you call `session.connect` in your code

Comment: Can you include the logs as per [my comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30225010/enable-compression-with-jsch?noredirect=1#comment48564455_30225010)?